# most efficient sql for retrieval

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
 ----------------
|   X    |   Y   |
 ----------------
|   a    |   1   |
|   c    |   6   |
|   e    |   3   |
|   d    |   6   |
|   c    |   4   |
|   b    |   1   |
|   a    |   5   |
|   g    |   1   |
 ----------------
```

When I'm given an array [c,d] I need to find "6" in the table above. I.e. for every set of elements I need to find the Y value that is shared by all the elements in the set but only if there is no other element (i.e. an element that's not in the given array) that shares that value. The number of elements in the array has no theoretical limits.

More examples: for [a,b,c] I need to find nothing. For [a,b] I also need to find nothing (because g also has an entry for Y = 1, so for [a,b,g] I do need to find "1").

I could of course iterate over the array, query by query, but that seems such an inefficient way of doing it. What's the best way of doing this in SQL? Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Are you trying to pass your "array" into the query using an IN list?

Comment: What RMDB are you using?

Comment: Best is subjective. It depends on what data you have, what database and version you use, and what indexes are available.

Comment: Well I haven't tried anything obviously, I'm thinking about the problem in my head. If I do "where X in [a,b]" I would find "1,5" which is not what I want.

Comment: ok forget "best" or "most efficient". Try reasonably efficient. I'm using MySQL but any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way by having your "query" values in a separate table.

```
create table t ( x varchar(1), y int);

insert into t (x, y) values ('a', 1);
insert into t (x, y) values ('c', 6);
insert into t (x, y) values ('e', 3);
insert into t (x, y) values ('d', 6);
insert into t (x, y) values ('c', 4);
insert into t (x, y) values ('b', 1);
insert into t (x, y) values ('a', 5);
insert into t (x, y) values ('g', 1);

create table q ( x varchar(1) );

insert into q (x) values ('a');
insert into q (x) values ('b');

select a.y from
(
   select t.y
     from t join q on (t.x = q.x)
   group by t.y
   having count(*) = (select count(*) from q)
) a 
join t on (a.y = t.y) 
group by a.y
having count(*) = (select count(*) from q)
```

[Here's an example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c8c/1).

This assumes that you can't have duplicate combinations.

If you want to do it without the second table, you can replace the `select count(*)` with the number of values you are matching to in an IN list, and instead of doing the join on the inner subquery, use a where clause.

```
select a.y from
(
select t.y
from t
  where t.x in ('c', 'd')
group by t.y
having count(*) = 2
) a 
join t on (a.y = t.y) 
group by a.y
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Need a GROUP BY in the outer queries.  But nice lateral thinking to do it with a single table.  I think the LEFT JOIN approach will be less intensive (one join and one group by, instead of two joins and two group bys), but performance will be very poor either way so this seems good to me!  (+1)

Comment: @Dems - Thanks. MySQL doesn't need the group by since it implicitly groups, but probably should include it for ease of readability.

Comment: @NWest: I really like your second solution, that's astute, seems to work too. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent - Try all the solutions. These queries scale VERY badly, just by their nature. Depending on the size of your data, and the frequency that you run the query, you may want to work out which has fewer reads and cpu time.  This is the type of query where more code is often a sound investment in reaping better performance.

Comment: Thanks @Dems it's going to be a big table indeed. I'm trying to find a way out of remodelling the database for this problem (not my work). But it's clear how inefficient this is going to be. Trading off 3 extra days of work for an inefficient query. Not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

These types of query are *never* particularly performant over large data-sets and/or where many values in Y shares the same values in X.

That said, this is the simple version of my normal way of doing it...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE params (
  item VARCHAR(16)
)
INSERT INTO params SELECT 'a'
INSERT INTO params SELECT 'b'
INSERT INTO params SELECT 'g'


SELECT
  yourTable.Y
FROM
  yourTable
LEFT JOIN
  params
    ON yourTable.X = params.item
GROUP BY
  yourTable.Y
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT yourTable.X) = COUNT(DISTINCT params.item)
```

Another option that doesn't need a parameters table, though I don't think it is more performant...

```
SELECT
  y
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  y
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT x) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN x IN ('a', 'b', 'g') THEN x ELSE NULL END)
```

This has no joins, but is at the expense of doing a full table scan.

Comment: That would also yield true for {a,b}  count=2. His example with {a,b} (eg without g) should not yield anything. (if I understood correctly) BTW: this looks like sudeku ...

Comment: @wildplasser - Good spot, I didn't read that bit ***oops***. Updated to LEFT JOIN on a table and updated the HAVING to state that both sides must have the same number of distinct items.

Comment: @Dems, this solution is probably good too so thanks a lot, but I'm using symfony and DQL so I'd like to steer clear of creating param tables. And I definitely don't want a full table scan.

Comment: @Vincent - Seems good, but I still recommend testing all the options ;)  `1.` If you don't use a parameter table you're doing multiple joins, scanning most of the table, sorting for a group by, another scan of most of the table, and another sort for the group by.  But you have a simpler query to handle.  `2.` If you use a parameter table you drastically reduce the amount of reads, and probably get a noticable performance benefit.  `3.`  Either way, you actually scan a *lot* of the table anyway, but a bit here and a bit there.  This means that a straight single scan *may* yield a boost.

Comment: @Vincent - I agree with Dems - You should definitely test every possibility, as this can get very bad very quickly as the table grows.  Remember, [Everything is fast for small n](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/everything-is-fast-for-small-n.html).

Comment: @NWest, ok thanks. Because the query is bound to be inefficient, I've decided I will just go get all distinct Y values, and then intersect arrays on the php side. I suppose this will be faster as it's just a bunch of direct lookups, and then intersects.

Comment: @Vincent - I very much doubt that sending all your data across a network, to be filtered by php, will be faster than doing it locally.  You're suggesting a full table scan, large network traffic, and high local CPU cost.  Any of the answers here will probably be better than that.

Comment: @Dems well here's what I was planning to do: 1) fetch all Y for "a" 2) fetch all Y for "b" 3) php intersect those two results 4) foreach Z in the intersection count all Y where X is not a or b. If 0 then add Z to result.
Isn't breaking it down into simpler queries like this going to help you think?

Comment: @vincent you have to get back c, d, e, f, etc, as well.  Because you want to exclude all Y that have more than just {a,b}.  And why not do the intersect in SQL.  In my experience you just won't be able to beat the SQL only options.  The reason the SQL will be slow *compared to other queries*, is just that this problem doesn't have an elegant solution.  It's not SQL that will make it relatively slow, the very nature of the problem makes it slow in *all* languages.  But a basic principle should be to Test and Compare *all* of your options.

Comment: @Dems ok thanks man, I will definitely see if I can do some comparing. I don't have to get back c, d, e etc. though. Following my previous post: 1) gives me [1,5] 2) gives me [1] 3) (intersection) gives me [1] 4) gives me "g".

Because 4) doesn't give me an empty result, I shouldn't consider the [1]. If 4 gave me an empty array (i.e. X=g Y=1 didn't exist) then I add [1] to the result. But thank you for your thoughts! =)